# Transaction using JSF2, EJB3, JPA2

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, ejb

What is the best way to handle transactions in this environment?

I have a Transacao class, which has a collection of Transacao.

```
public class Transacao {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pai")
    private List<Transacao> filhos;
}
```

I load this in JSF from a EJB, something like:

```
public class TransacaoBean {

    @EJB
    private TransacaoService transacaoService;

    private void edit(Long id) {
        this.transacao = transacaoService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

although, if I want to get the collection of filhos, I have to do this:

```
public class TransacaoBean {

    ...

    private void edit(Long id) {
        this.transacao = transacaoService.findById(id);
        log.info(this.transacao.getFilhos.size()); //this throws a LazyInitializationException
    }
}
```

and I get an Exception.

What is the best way to have this loaded in my JSF? I'm considering creating a `Filter` and using `USerTransaction` to keep the transaction open for the request or fetching the filhos in my EJB. Is there a better solution to this, which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch`'s default value of the `@OneToMany` is `FetchType.LAZY`.

You can set it `FetchType.EAGER` to use them in non-managed environment.

Or you can make another EJB or method for getting a list or just the size.

```
public class TransacaoService {

    public Transacao findById(final long id) {
        ...
    }

    public long getFilhosSize(final long id) {
        // SELECT f FROM Transacao AS t WHERE t.pai.id=:id
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```